# Installing PostgreSQL 11 with default custom cluster

Tags: postgresql

We are setting up a virtual machine with Vagrant ( ubuntu/focal64 )  and we are using some shell scripts to handle Postgres 11 installation. What we want to achieve is initializing the default cluster with specific locale settings. The wanted behavior is similar to installing PostgreSQL on a Windows machine using the EDB installer and specifying the collation, encoding etc.. before installation. How can we do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Debian / Ubuntu packages for PostgreSQL are annoying in that they automatically create a database cluster during installation. You'll have to remove that and create it again:

```sh
pg_dropcluster --stop 11 main
pg_createcluster 11 main -- -E UTF8 --locale=ar_YE.utf8 --lc-messages=C
```

You have to choose a locale that exists on your operating system. `locale -a` lists them, and `locale-gen` creates a new one.

Comment: The behavior I get is really weird ! I included your suggested commands with a slight modification and I still get  C.UTF-8 for all my locale variables.                                                                                                     `pg_dropcluster --stop 11 main
 pg_createcluster 11 main -- -E UTF8 --locale=en_US.utf8`

Comment: I have added hints about the locale.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Actually, `en_US.utf8` is part of the locale list available. Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Yes, that is weird. Perhaps you could create a new question that contains the output of `locale -a | grep en_US`, your exact commands and the exact response and the output of `\l` in psql.

Comment: Well I want to thank you very much @Laurenz because it's working fine although locale is rendering  `C.UT8` type

Comment: That may make `ORDER BY` return results in a different order than you expect.

Comment: Oddly, after testing it on several tables in the db, it is working fine ! We are scratching our heads around why `locale` isn't showing the correct values. When we run `SHOW LC_COLLATE` we get the `en_US` collation.

Comment: Perhaps there are two different PostgreSQL instances? At any rate, running `\l` in `psql` will show you the settings for all databases.